# USB redirection in libvirt

Tags: usb, virtualization, fedora, libvirt

I'm running libvirt under Fedora 28. I would like to attach a USB
device to a VM, but when I select "Redirect USB Device" from the
"Virtual Machine" menu in virt-manager and then select the device, I
get the error:

> USB redirection error
>
> spice-client-error-quark: Could not redirect [device name] at 1-11:
>   Error setting USB device node ACL: 'Not authorized' (0)

There are no additional log messages acccompanying this in either the
journal or in audit.log.  It's not a selinux issue.  The "Details"
dropdown in the error dialog helpfully adds "USB redirection error".

What do I do with this error message? I'm not even sure what it's
trying to tell me.

Comment: What are you trying to pass-through and why?

Comment: I am trying to pass through a keyboard in order to apply a firmware update to it. However, it turns out that this particular problem goes away with a more recent version of the software. Still not clear what the error message is indicating or how to solve it, so if you have any ideas on that an answer is still appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some research you have encountered a bug. Here is the best voted solution I found but I can't test as I don't have your setup.

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/udev/rules.d/50-spice.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GROUP="spice", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", GROUP="spice", MODE="0660"
EOF

usermod -a -G spice $USER
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and see if that was the problem.